# Hql query similar to SaveOrUpdate in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

We have `saveOrUpdate(Object)` function in Hibernate while we use Session and it is easier as we don't have to check whether to perform save or update. but the `insert(Object)` and `update(Object)` functions are only there for Stateless Session and i need to use the stateless session as i go with hundreds of thousands of records and hibernate is eating up the memory. Is there any way to replicate the `saveOrUpdate(Object)` functionality in Stateless Session. or anyway by using Hql query instead of using object to do it through hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the StatelessSession JavaDoc

> A stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor
>   interact with any second-level cache, nor does it implement
>   transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking, nor do
>   operations cascade to associated instances. Collections are ignored by
>   a stateless session. Operations performed via a stateless session
>   bypass Hibernate's event model and interceptors. Stateless sessions
>   are vulnerable to data aliasing effects, due to the lack of a
>   first-level cache

It doesn't maintain first-level cache hence doesn't know the current state of the object (Transient, Persistent, Detached or Removed) hence it cannot make a conscious decision. You can query using HQL to find if the same record exist or not in the database and call the respective method to `insert()` or `update()`. But this is a costly.

If there are lakh's of records to be updated or inserted it would be best to use basic JDBC rather than hibernate. That will solve your memory problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..i was trying to find out a way to do it through hibernate without effecting the memory. while i tried by using the stateless session then i could control the memory usage.